# Implementing UISlider With Animation in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I'm fairly new to Objective C and I'm having some trouble with how to implement UISlider with Animation. I want to use the slider to change the speed of an animation (which is an image changing its size once the Animate button is clicked) but I couldn't figure out how to connect the slider with the duration of the animation. So I would like to ask for suggestion on ways to make it work. (I pre-set the minimum value of the slider to 1, the max value to 5, and the default to 3). Any suggestion would be appreciated. Here are my ViewController.m code

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Project5-TMN
//
//  Created by Lab on 4/6/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Toan Nguyen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speedValue;
- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)speed:(UISlider *)sender;


@end

@implementation ViewController
// Declare two variables to hold the width and height of the image
float w, h;
// Declare a global variable to set the animation status
BOOL animating = YES;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // set w to the size of the image width
    w = _image.bounds.size.width;

    // set h to the size of the image height
    h = _image.bounds.size.height;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {
    // set animation status to YES again to let it animating continously after stop
    animating = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^ {
        // Create a CGRect rect, and set the core graphic Rect to the image bound
        CGRect rect = _image.bounds;

        // Set the width of rect to the difference of the bounds of rect and the image width
        rect.size.width = w - rect.size.width;

        // Set the height of rect to the difference of the bounds of rect and the image height
        rect.size.height = h - rect.size.height;

        // Assign rect to the image bounds
        _image.bounds = rect;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            if (animating) {
                [self animate:sender];
            }
        }

    }];

}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    // set animating to NO
    animating = NO;

}

- (IBAction)speed:(UISlider *)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    _speedValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", slider.value];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the speed of animation you may change the value of duration. At your example you have constant duration 5 seconds at line:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^ {
```

Instead of constant 5 you can redirect value from slider. At your example you just show slider value at label but don't use it for animation parameter. You can use value of this label like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:[_speedValue.text intValue] delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^ {
```

Or you can create outlet for slider and use it value directly:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *speedSlider; //this line at interface should be created by control drag from slider to code

[UIView animateWithDuration:_speedSlider.value delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^ {
```

Or you can use some kind of buffer variable:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) float currentSpeed; // declare at interface

[UIView animateWithDuration:_currentSpeed delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^ { // at - (IBAction)animate:(id)sender

self.currentSpeed = slider.value; // at - (IBAction)speed:(UISlider *)sender
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions Anton! I'll definitely try these out to see if it works